# Long division of $\frac{3x^3-x^2-13x-13}{x^2-x-6}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

I'm self-studying from Stroud & Booth's amazing textbook "Engineering Mathematics", and am on the "Partial Fractions" chapter. As part of an exercise I need to do long division of two polynomial equations.

The problem is, long division of polynomials was never explained in the textbook. The long division I need to do is this one:

$$\frac{3x^3-x^2-13x-13}{x^2-x-6}$$

The book states that the result is:

$$3x+2+\frac{7x-1}{x^2-x-6}$$

But the mechanics of the long division are never explained. Can I please get some help with this one?

Comment: See [this](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_long_division).  It’s like long division of numbers

Comment: (1) Order the polynomials according to some monomial order. The one needed here is according to decreasing degrees. Increasing degrees is used if you were computing Taylor series expansion, for example. (2) While degree of the current numerator is strictly larger than degree of denominator, divide largest term of the numerator by largest term of the denominator. This will be a new term of the quotient. (3) Multiply the whole denominator by the newly added term in the quotient and subtract it from the numerator. the result is the new numerator. (4) Go to 2.

Answer (score 3):

For long division, you essentially keep reducing the degree of the numerator until it's lower than the denominator.

In the example you gave, $\displaystyle \frac{3x^3 - x^2 - 13x - 13}{x^2 - x- 6}$, we first look at the leading term, $3x^3$. We now want to remove this from the numerator, so we multiply $x^2-x-6$ by $3x$ to obtain $3x^3 - 3x^2 - 18x$. We now write the numerator with this term in it: $$\displaystyle \frac{3x^3 - x^2 - 13x - 13}{x^2 - x- 6} = \frac{(3x^3 - 3x^2 - 18x) + 2x^2 + 5x - 13}{x^2 - x- 6} = 3x + \frac{2x^2 + 5x - 13}{x^2 - x- 6}.$$
We now repeat the process again; we remove the leading term $x^2$on the numerator by multiplying $x^2-x-6$ by $2$ to obtain $2x^2 - 2x - 12$, and then write the numerator with this term:
$$3x + \frac{2x^2 + 5x - 13}{x^2 - x- 6} = 3x + \frac{(2x^2 -2x - 12) + 7x - 1}{x^2 - x- 6} = 3x + 2 + \frac{7x-1}{x^2-x-6}.$$
The numerator now has lower degree than the denominator, and so we stop.

Answer (score 3):

The algorithm is straightforward and is loosely similar to the usual long division of decimal numbers as follows:

1. Find the quotient of the leading term in the numerator divided by the leading term in the denominator.  In your case, $3x^3/x^2 = 3x$.
2. Multiply the quotient in step 1 by the denominator.  You should get $3x^3 - 3x^2 - 18x$.
3. Subtract the numerator from the result in step 2.  You should have $3x^3 - x^2 - 13x - 13 - (3x^3 - 3x^2 - 18x) = 2x^2 + 5x - 13$.  This is the remainder from the first cycle.
4. If the degree of the remainder in step 3 is less than the degree of the denominator, stop.  Otherwise, repeat steps 1-3 with the result from step 3 as your new numerator.  $2x^2/x^2 = 2$, so the next quotient is $2$.

Upon completion, you should have quotients $3x$, $2$, and a remainder of $7x-1$.

Answer (score 3):

First, you see which monomial you must multiply $x^2-x-6$ by in order to get something close to $3x^2-x^2-13x-13$. Clearly, that would be $3x$: $3x(x^2-x-6)=3x^3-3x^2-18x$. Now, you subtract this from $3x^2-x^2-13x-13$:$$3x^2-x^2-13x-13-(3x^3-3x^2-18x)=2x^2+5x-13.$$Now, you start all over again. What is the monomial you must multiply $x^2-x-6$ by in order to get something close to $2x^2+5x-13$? Clearly, it is $2$: $2(x^2-x-6)=2x^2-2x-12$. Now, you subtract this from $2x^2+5x-13$:$$2x^2+5x-13-(2x^2-2x-12)=7x-1.$$Since you now have a polynomial whose degree is smaller than the degree of the polynomial that you are dividing by, you're done:

- the quotient is the sum of the monomials that you got: $3x+2$;
- that final polynomial ($7x-1$) is the remainder.

Answer (score 1):

Polynomial long division is exactly same as long division of decimals.
With respect to your posed problem here are steps.

**Step1:** We have to divide $3x^3-x^2-\dots$ with $x^2$, so we first multiply the divisor $(x^2-x-6)$ by $3x$ to give $3x^3$. THen we subtract and copy the remaining terms.

**Step2:** Again now we have $2x^2+5x-13$ and we have to divide by $x^2-x-6$. So we multiply our divisor by $2$.

Finally, we get $3x+2$ as dividend and $7x-1$ as remainder. Now recall if we had  $\frac{17}{3}$ we would write it as $5+\frac{2}{3}$. Here $\bf{2}$ is remainder.

Similarly we write our result of long division as $$3x+2+\frac{7x-1}{x^2-x-6}$$

[image]